# Getting the gin context when it's not passed in?

Tags: go, go-gin

New to go/gin and I am trying to understand how to access the gin context in a situation where you are getting a callback from a 3rd party library.

```
gin.GET("/someurl", someHandler)

...

func someHandler(c *gin.Context) {

  // pass request off to third party lib that will call our GetSession() method later
  // the third party does not take a gin context, only http request and writer

  3rdpartylib.HandleRequest(c.Writer, c.Request)  

}

func (t *THINGY) GetSession(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  // How do I get the gin context for the request back?

}
```

Does gin put a reference to itself in the request object somewhere?

If not, should I stash a reference in the request object myself?

Comment: How does the 3rd party call the `GetSession` method? Via HTTP redirect? That's a different HTTP call, with a different context.

Comment: It should be called during the course of the same request. Sorry I should have called that out

Comment: How does the 3rd party library do that? How does it know the `*t`?

Comment: t.3rdparty.SessionProvider = t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it in the request context:

```
newCtx:=context.WithValue(Request.Context(),"session",c)
3rdpartylib.HandleRequest(c.Writer, c.Request.WithContext(newCtx))  
...
func (t *THINGY) GetSession(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  c:=r.Context().Value("session").(*gin.Context)
}
```

Comment: It's r.Context().Value though, correct?